# How can I subtract non-working schedule from a Working schedule to generate a new table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a standardized working schedule that can look something like this for one particular day:

```
Working Shift   PayDay      StartTime           EndTime
True    Shift1  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 06:00    2020-09-14 14:00
True    Shift2  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 14:00    2020-09-14 23:00
True    Shift3  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 23:00    2020-09-15 06:00
```

Then I have another table with deviations from the above working schedule, that can look like this:

```
Working Shift   PayDay      StartTime           EndTime
False   Shift1  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 10:00    2020-09-14 12:30
```

From these tables, I would like to generate one single table, showing only the available working hours. This table should then look something like this:

```
Working Shift   PayDay      StartTime           EndTime
True    Shift1  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 06:00    2020-09-14 10:00
True    Shift1  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 12:30    2020-09-14 14:00
True    Shift2  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 14:00    2020-09-14 23:00
True    Shift3  2020-09-14  2020-09-14 23:00    2020-09-15 06:00
```

In this case, because I have non-working hours in the middle of shift 1, the result table will have two entries for that shift.

I'm a new to SQL and have no idea how to solve this, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you not just after a `UNION ALL`?

Comment: So the first record is "split" because the record in the second dataset splits it. Your first step is to write a select query that identifies all the records in the the first table that need to be split. Also I assume these tables have a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could view the answer in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6ad6e5c14da9e9c90b91aa22526db40c).
For future use, the tables creation query could be:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( 
  [Working] [nvarchar](25),
  [Shift] [nvarchar](25),
  [PayDay] [nvarchar](25),
  [StartTime] datetime,
  [EndTime] datetime)
  
CREATE TABLE table2 ( 
  [Working] [nvarchar](25),
  [Shift] [nvarchar](25),
  [PayDay] [nvarchar](25),
  [StartTime] datetime,
  [EndTime] datetime)

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
('True', 'Shift1', '2020-09-14', '2020-09-14 06:00', '2020-09-14 14:00'),
('True', 'Shift2', '2020-09-14', '2020-09-14 14:00', '2020-09-14 23:00')

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES 
('False', 'Shift1', '2020-09-14', '2020-09-14 10:00', '2020-09-14 12:30')
```

As you need a new table with more lines than the previous one, you could work a solution around `UNION` as indicated in the comments. After that, logical parameters could be applied to create your view. `Final_EndTime` is created by taking the next `StartTime` and only for the last entry the `EndTime` is used. While `Final_StartTime` is using the `EndTime` when `Working` column is `False`.

```
SELECT 'True' AS Final_Working, A.PayDay, A.Shift,
  CASE WHEN A.Working = 'False' THEN A.EndTime ELSE A.StartTime END AS Final_StartTime,
  CASE WHEN LEAD(A.Working) OVER (ORDER BY A.StartTime) <> '' THEN LEAD(A.StartTime) OVER (ORDER BY A.StartTime) ELSE A.EndTime END AS Final_EndTime
FROM (
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
UNION ALL 
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 AS t2)A
ORDER BY A.StartTime
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This was exactly what I was looking for